# How to setup php pointing out from webroot?

Tags: php, system

I have this line in one file that tries to locate the EE system folder. It works just fine if the folder is inside webroot. But in my case, my folder is out from webroot and I'm totally helpless what changes I need to add to this, so it can locate the folder. Help would be nice, thanks.

```
include_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mySYSTEMfolder'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'expressionengine'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'database.php');
```

Comment: What do you mean "out"? Is it a child path of the web root and not functioning? Your PHP agent (apache, nginx, etc...) won't interpret and serve PHP files in a directory it isn't supposed to... if it's a *nix file, you could add an interpreter shebang to the PHP cli.

Comment: Its above public_html, thats what i ment.

Comment: Well like I said, if it lives in a directory that is not being served by your PHP agent, it shouldn't be executing at all. Can probably help you if you post your directory structure for where the file is and where it's supposed to point.

Comment: Everyone knows that the normal EE setup is something like /public_html/system. Now its system/public_html because i have set those post-installation best practises in place to add security. and the file the is looking for "system" is at public_html/foo/. Site is working just fine, but this extra add-on (not related to EE) is just trying to grab some data from conf and database to it can track down member_id.